# How to open Chrome using its icon on left bar of Ubuntu 20.04, just by using keyboard, no mouse

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, google-chrome, icons

In Windows, we can press C key to point to chrome icon and then press the Enter key to launch chrome.
Similarly, how can we open chrome using just the keyboard, and using the Chrome's icon present on the left side of Homescreen in Ubuntu 20.04 OS?

In other words, this question is not specific to just Chrome. I want to know the method to use keyboard to point to any icon present in Favourites on the left bar of  screen. I do not want to use mouse.

[Attaching the screenshot showing the favourite icons on the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3TyB.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Favorites on your dock can be launched (or switched to if they are already running) with the shortcut keys <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd>. Thus, if your Chromium would be the first icon on the dock, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will launch it or bring it into focus if it is already running.